# Getting an object's numerical position in a list

Tags: list, haskell

Is there any way to determine an object's numerical position in a list? That is in the list [1, 2, 3, 4] 1 would have the position of 0 and in the list "Hello, World!" l would have the position of 2? I tried to make a counter that bumped up while it was reading the list, but forgot Haskell doesn't allow variables to change. Any help is appreciated and thank you for reading

Comment: make your counter variable a parameter to your function and call the function recursively with counter + 1 to bump up the counter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) for this variety of question. For example, I just tried the (wrong, it turns out) type signature `[a] -> a -> Int` there, and the top two results were

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
```

which do just what you ask. Take a look at their source if you're curious how.

Comment: Will do and thanks for the link. Now I can cut back on the searching I have to do

Comment: Fortunately Hoogle is smart enough to try swapping the order of parameters.

Comment: @Dan Yep, and to try adding typeclasses, and also to try adding type constructors in arbitrary places! It really massaged my wrong type a lot before finding a result.